# Inverse of Matrix inv(A*inv(B)*A')

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following form:
$$
(AB^{-1}A^T)^{-1}
$$
with $A \in R^{M \times N}$ and $B \in R^{N \times N}$ and is invertible. And there is $M<N$.

How can we "open the bracket" of the above expression correctly?

Comment: You cannot multiply an $N\times 1$ vector by an $N\times N$ matrix on the right.  Maybe you want $A$ to be an $1\times N$ vector instead?

Comment: If $A\in F^{N\times 1}$, how can such matrix multiply with $B^{-1}\in F^{N\times N}$?

Comment: MathJax tip: In addition to display maths, i.e. surrounded by `$$`, you can also do inline maths, surrounded by `$`. For example, to put $(AB^{-1}A^T)^{-1}$ as I just did there, I wrote `$(AB^{-1}A^T)^{-1}$`. Note that you can put these in titles as well. Further, if you want a nice multiplication, `$N \times 1$` produces $N \times 1$.

Comment: @user10354138, Hi, sorry I have already corrected the error in the original question.

Comment: I am not sure is this correct hint, but in general: the inverse of a product of several invertible matrices is the product of the inverses, in the opposite order. In other words: $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak As $A$ and $A^\top$ are square, they are not invertible. A handy thing to remember, but unfortunately not applicable here. I don't know of a helpful, alternative way of expressing this inverse, but that's not to say there isn't one.

Comment: To @TheoBendit: Thanks for your remark. I agree.